# How to control a zooming speed in D3 V4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently studying Mike Bostock's zoom functionality from this bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/431a331294d2b5ddd33f947cf4c81319 and I realized that the speed of the intro zoom can be controlled from this line:

```
.duration(1500)
```

Is there also such a way to control the zooming on scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the `wheelDelta` function
Make a wheel delta function

```
function myDelta() {
  return -d3.event.deltaY * (d3.event.deltaMode ? 120 : 1) / 1500;
}
```

You may increase the constant 1500 to any number of your choice for regulating the delta.

Now in zoom define the wheelDelta like this:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 32])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .wheelDelta(myDelta)//your function
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_wheelDelta)

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l0uRNn5ja6UxdvVoTXjD?p=preview)

Comment: deltaMode is 1 in my case. When does it change and what other values could it have?

Comment: Oh it's not something from d3. It's this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaMode